# How can I convert Matlab's boolean() function to Octave function?

Tags: matlab, boolean, octave

```
ftype = boolean([1,1,1,0]); 
% boolean indicator to select feature types
```

I have the code above, and the boolean() function is not working in my octave.

How can I convert Matlab's boolean() function to Octave function?

Comment: As you know, Octave is a Matlab's open source clone. but In Octave, thera are some incompatablility to matlab.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
ftype = logical([1,1,1,0]);

whos ftype;

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        ftype        1x4                         4  logical
```

The logical function is supported by both `Octave` and `Matlab`:

- [Octave Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Logical-Values.html)
- [Matlab Reference](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're using `boolean`. It's part of Simulink and pretty much does nothing other than call [`logical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html). You should just be using `logical` within Matlab, and Octave has [equivalent syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Logical-Values.html).